# How to avoid Webdatarocks filter function to avoid linking filter in charts and Pivot table

Tags: highcharts, webdatarocks

[1]  I have a webpage having Webdatarocks Pivot table and Highcharts(integrated with webdatarocks).
I have a requirement where I need to show  chart with some filtered data, so I am using getdata() function of WebDataRocks, which act as datasource for Highcharts.
Issue which I am facing is soon I apply filter in the getdata() function, it also applies filter in Webdatarocks Pivot Grid.
Even though both Pivot grid and highcharts are independent and this way it filter my Pivot grid as well which is not required.
Any solution to this highly appreciated.

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klku1.png)

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor that I could work on?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `slice` property of the `highcharts.getData` API call would help since it defines the subset of data to display in charts. Here is an [online sample](https://codepen.io/webdatarocks/pen/LYbWZJN) where the `slice` property is set on line 33.

And here is a [reference to the corresponding docs](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/highcharts-getdata/).